# Is this static route configuration incorrect?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

I have a server on my local network which I cannot reach when connecting wirelessly. However, it's working fine when connecting directly via the network device the server is connected to.

When connecting wirelessly, I'm not connecting to the ASUS router, but a **access point on 192.168.1.126** that is connected to the ASUS router.

**ASUS Router** (192.168.1.1)

-> LAN1: **Access point** (192.168.1.126)

-> LAN2: **ZyWALL** (192.168.1.129) -> **Server** (172.16.5.30).

Connecting directly to the ZyWALL through one of the LAN ports on it, the server is reached. When connecting via WIFI that goes via the access point it doesnt work.

The ASUS router has a configured static route to the server that looks like this:

Network/IP: **172.16.5.0**

Net Mask: **255.255.255.0**

Gateway: **192.168.1.129**

Metric: **2**

Interface: **LAN**

When I ping the server while using wireless connectivity on my laptop i get the following results:
Now when I ping the server i get the following result:

```
PING 172.16.5.30 (172.16.5.30): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
92 bytes from router.asus.com (192.168.1.1): Redirect Host(New addr: 192.168.1.129)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
4  5  00 0054 129f   0 0000  3f  01 f5b5 192.168.1.126  172.16.5.30
```

The ping result looks like the server ip is attempted to be resolved by the access point, however there isn't a static route for that device telling that the server should be routed via the ZyWALL.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please verify the ping command output. It was mangled in your question. I tried to fix it, but may have gotten it wrong. Please use the Code Block feature when providing console output and text file contents of any kind (configuration, log, ...).

Comment: OK. Please clarify your network hierarchy. Especially what network segments are involved. Do you have two segments (both connected to “ASUS Router”) that have the *192.168.1.0/24* network?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes both the AP and the ZyWALL is connected to each own LAN port on the ASUS router.

Answer (score 0):

The route is correct. (Redirects are your router's way of saying "you can reach that gateway directly, without going through me" – but usually they are completely optional.)

Use `tcpdump` on the server to check whether ping requests actually *arrive:*

```
tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 icmp
```

It's possible that your *server* does not have a route back to the `192.168.1.0` LAN, and therefore cannot reply back. It might need a similar static route via ZyWALL.

Though, if you can, also check whether the ZyWALL *itself* is receiving (and forwarding) the requests. (Depending on firmware, it might have Telnet → `sh` → `tcpdump` available.)

---

(Note that your Wi-Fi access point's address is usually completely irrelevant. The AP – well, if it's actually a AP – acts no different from an Ethernet switch, working at a layer below IP.)